# Force some composite type fields to be unique?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create multiple image paths based on the language and size of the image. I decided to **CREATE TYPE** and then use it in the table.

```
CREATE DATABASE asset (
  id bigserial not null constraint primary key,
  main_image img[]
);

CREATE TYPE img AS (
  lang varchar(2) not null,
  size varchar(32) not null,
  img_path varchar(255) not null
);
```

How do I make something like this: unique(lang, size) for my composite type? I want this combo to be unique.

How do I restrict any inserts that try to add an **img_path** for lang & size combo that already has **img_path** defined? I have tried to **CREATE DOMAIN**, but it seems like it is not intended for it.

Comment: Do you want those `(lang, size)` tuples to be unique within the `main_image` array (ie not unique across rows)? If so, you would probably be better off with normalizing your schema, ie creating a `main_images` table with a FK on `asset(id)` and one row per image.

Comment: I though about it, but I wanted to use them in order to implement multiple languages in my app.  How do I implement multiple languages then?

Comment: you can use trigger to check before insert that data is already present or not.